# How do I validate a datepicker entry with a 3 character month?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

Currently I have a datepicker set that makes it so that you can't enter an End Date before the Start Date. I'd like to modify it to validate if there has been an invalid entry such as invalid characters or an invalid date. Typically, I think I'd just parse the date entered, but since I'm using a 3 character month, I don't think it's that easy? If it ends up being too difficult, I may have to resort to a different date format.

Current 3 character month datePicker:

```
$("#slt-date-from").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yyMdd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear : true,
    numberOfMonths : 1,
    minDate: '-10y',
    maxDate: '-1',
    onSelect: function(date){

        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

       //Set Minimum Date of EndDatePicker After Selected Date of StartDatePicker
        $("#slt-date-to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
        $("#slt-date-to").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", '+1y' );

    }
});

$("#slt-date-to").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yyMdd',
    changeMonth: true,  
    changeYear : true,
    numberOfMonths : 1,
});
```

Comment: why not just use html5 date input? all of the hard work has already been done for you.

Comment: Because it's not compatible with internet explorer from the looks of it.